# tcsh way of pattern substitution

Tags: bash, tcsh, csh

I am using tcsh shell with Jenkins. In short, the matching suffix should be removed from the output.

Achieved in bash with the following.

```
cd ${WORKSPACE%${JOB_NAME}}
```

Case:

Given the following variables:

```
WORKSPACE = "/abc/def/ghi/jkl"
JOB_NAME = "ghi/jkl"
```

The excepted output is:

```
/abc/def
```

With bash, `echo ${WORKSPACE%${JOB_NAME}}` would return `abc/def` for the example above.
How can I achieve this with tcsh?

I have tried a few things:

```
echo "/abc/def/ghi/jkl" | sed "s|'ghi/jkl'|' '|g"
```

In this case, the output was: `/abc/def/ghi/jkl`, but I expected `/abc/def/`.

Comment: @drewk, in csh, assignment is with `set var = value`, not `var=value` (nor `var = value`)

Comment: Don't use tcsh, there's no reason to be using tcsh in this century. Doing anything reliably is virtually impossible in that shell. If you're looking for a better shell than bash, look at zsh, rc, yash, fish or es, looking at tcsh would be looking backwards.

Comment: In `bash` or ksh where that syntax comes from or any POSIX shell, that should rather be `cd -P -- "${WORKSPACE%"$JOB_NAME"}"` (bearing in mind that if the suffix is not found `$WORKSPACE` is expanded as-is).